# Different types of verbs

Tags: terminology, verbs

There are different types of verbs in languages. I am interested in formal name of these types. I want to distinguish between verbs that don't have  antonyms and synonyms simultaneously, like 'see', 'hear'. and verbs that do have antonyms and synonyms, like 'accept', antonym: 'reject', synonym: 'agree'.

I wonder whether these two groups have formal definition?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE. Please provide with some more examples, preferably, in several languages. I'm not sure this question can be answered as it currently is.

Comment: @bytebuster, done!

Comment: "Antonym" is an ill-defined concept, especially for verbs (it is more supportable for adjectives, though still problematic). In your examples, the relationship between "accept" and "reject" is entirely different from the relationship between "appear" and "disappear".

Comment: Well, for "see" we have synonyms "look," "view," "watch," "spot," and "spy" as in "I spy with my little eye."    For "hear" we have "listen" and "overhear."    Of course, these are not *exact* synonyms, but I don't know whether exact synonyms exist, or whether "synonym" is precisely defined.  Also, at the risk of sounding like Alex Trebek, you need to phrase your question as a question.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann, done!